# Multi-Dimensional Array class error

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, operators

This code worked fine until I added the `rot()` function. Yes, it is declared properly in the header file. I replaced all the equation with simple 1.0f values  but the same error occurred. That hints to me that it has something to do with declaring Matrix2f rot; ...Does anyone have any clue what the issue is here?

```
#include "Matrix2f.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector2f.h"

Matrix2f::Matrix2f(){

    m[0][0]= 1.0f;    m[0][1]= 0.0f;
    m[1][0]= 0.0f;    m[1][1]= 1.0f;

}

Vector2f Matrix2f::rot(float theta, Vector2f vec){

     Matrix2f rot;

        rot[0][0]= cosf(theta);  rot[0][1]= -sinf(theta);
        rot[1][0]= sinf(theta);  rot[1][1]= cosf(theta);

        float tx = ((rot[0][0]*vec.getX())+(rot[0][1]*vec.getY()));
        float ty = ((rot[1][0]*vec.getX())+(rot[1][1]*vec.getY()));


    return Vector2f(tx, ty);

}

void Matrix2f::printMat(){

    std::cout << "| " << m[0][0] << "    " << m[0][1] << " |" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "| " << m[1][0] << "    " << m[1][1] << " |" << std::endl;
}
```

The error the compiler gives:

```
|17|error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'rot[0]'|
```

it gives the same code twice for each line from line 17 through line 21...
Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: looks to be rot.m[0][0] ?

Comment: Show us the overload of `operator[]` in `Matrix2f`.  That's certainly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need "Matrix2f rot" object inside "rot" method.

You can change your method as:

```
Vector2f Matrix2f::rot(float theta, Vector2f vec){

    float tx = (( cosf(theta) * vec.getX())+( ( -sinf(theta) ) * vec.getY()));
    float ty = (( sinf(theta) * vec.getX())+( cosf(theta) * vec.getY()));

    return Vector2f(tx, ty);
}
```

Unless you want to reset the member variable "m" in "rot"( which I assume "float m[2][2]" )
then you can use:

```
Vector2f Matrix2f::rot(float theta, Vector2f vec){

    m[0][0]= cosf(theta);  m[0][1]= -sinf(theta);
    m[1][0]= sinf(theta);  m[1][1]= cosf(theta);

    float tx = (( m[0][0] * vec.getX())+( m[0][1] ) * vec.getY()));
    float ty = (( m[1][0] * vec.getX())+( m[1][1] * vec.getY()));

    return Vector2f(tx, ty);

}
```

You can not use rot[][] unless your class ( Matrix2f ) provides the implementation which overrides the operator []

Comment: Thanks it appears I over complicated the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the multidimensional array inside the object which is m. To do this, use rot.m as the multidimensional array.

Comment: But the constructor should take care of that on its own. In this case, any matrix declared initializes as the identity matrix. I'm not crating multidimensional array of multidimensional arrays.